# When I try to run the command "ar" to create my library I get "ar: libft.a: file format not recognized"

Tags: c, linux, unix, augmented-reality

This is the file .sh with the command to make the library:

```
gcc -c ft_putchar.c ft_swap.c ft_putstr.c ft_strcmp.c ft_strlen.c
ar -rc libft.h ft_putchar.o ft_swap.o ft_putstr.o ft_strcmp.o ft_strlen.o
rm -f *.o
```

This is the file .a with the functions:

```
#ifndef LIBFT_A
# define LIBFT_A

void    ft_putchar(char c);
void    ft_swap(int *a, int *b);
void    ft_putstr(char *str);
int     ft_strlen(char *str);
int     ft_strcmp(char *s1, char *s2);

#endif
```

Comment: im running this code on ubuntu 20.4.3 on windows

Answer (score 0):

For a start, I suspect you've entered the wrong error message in the title since you're attempting to create an archive file called `libft.h`:

```sh
ar -rc libft.h ft_putchar.o ft_swap.o ft_putstr.o ft_strcmp.o ft_strlen.o
#      ^^^^^^^
```

I'm not sure *why* you're trying to add all those object files to the *header* file. That's why it's complaining about the format, the header file is not an archive you can add to, as per:

```sh
pax:/mnt/c/Users/Pax/Documents/wsl> touch xx.h yy.o
pax:/mnt/c/Users/Pax/Documents/wsl> ar -rc xx.h yy.o
ar: xx.h: file format not recognized
```

If you want them to go to an existing archive, it needs to *be* an archive. If you want to create a new one, don't try to use an existing header file. In other words, this seems the more sensible option (note the archive file name rather than a header file):

```sh
ar -rc libft.a ft_putchar.o ft_swap.o ft_putstr.o ft_strcmp.o ft_strlen.o
```

Comment: can you explain more ?